# Matrix exponential of a non-nilpotent matrix?

Tags: matrices

An old exam problem asks to compute $e^{At}$ for 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 6\\ -3 & -4\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I compute a few powers of $A$, and it doesn't seem like $A$ is nilpotent, so $e^{At}$ is not finite. Is it a mistake, or is there some way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are ways.

Comment: @WillJagy I just realized I should diagonalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to compute exponent of a matrix is to diagonalize it. Provided this can be done, we can write the matrix as $A=Q^{-1}DQ$ with $D$ diagonal. Then
$$e^A = A + \frac{A^2}{2!}+\ldots = Q^{-1}DQ + \frac{Q^{-1}D^2Q}{2!}+\ldots=Q^{-1}e^DQ$$

Then, if $D=\textrm{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_n)$ we have $e^D = \textrm{diag}(e^{d_1}, \ldots, e^{d_n})$.